# Issue with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a very weird problem.

I have a php page with the following simple code:

```
echo $_POST["donaldduck"];
```

and the following script, calling with $.ajax the php page.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://provawhistletrip.altervista.org/tripview/ajaxtrip.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {donaldduck:"content"},
        onSuccess: function(){
              alert("boh");
        }        
  });
```

The problem is that I'm expecting to see an alert showing "boh" but I can't see any alert message, even an empty one.

P.S you can find the two pages here:

[the php page](http://provawhistletrip.altervista.org/tripview/ajaxtrip.php)

[the page with javascript](http://provawhistletrip.altervista.org/tripview/test/ajaxtrip_test.php)

Comment: I think you need to look at the API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and you probably want to add an `error` callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the success callback option is `success`, not `onSuccess`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://provawhistletrip.altervista.org/tripview/ajaxtrip.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        donaldduck: "content"
    },
    success: function() { // <== `success:`, not `onSuccess:`
        alert("boh");
    }

});
```

Comment: @Samuele: No worries.